# График работы по сменам

Tags: javascript

Подскажите решение реализации отображения текушей рабочей смены по графику 3-2.

Условия:

- Три рабочих дня, два выходных;
- Три смены **1** - с **23:00** (пред идущего дня смены, основной день указан как с 00:00 до 07:00) до **07:00**, **2** - с **07:00** до **15:00**, **3** - с **15:00** до **23:00**;
- Всего дежурных смен 5 - "А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д".

За начало можно взять от 01.01.2016 с следующими значениями (В - выходной):

- Смена "А": В В 1 1 1 В В 3 3 3 В В 2 2 2 (дальше по кругу);
- Смена "Б": В 3 3 3 В В 2 2 2 В В 1 1 1 В;
- Смена "В": 2 2 2 В В 1 1 1 В В 3 3 3 В В;
- Смена "Г": 1 1 В В 3 3 3 В В 2 2 2 В В 1;
- Смена "Д": 3 В В 2 2 2 В В 1 1 1 В В 3 3.

Есть решение, которое определяет номер смены (с учетом часа пред идущего дня).

```
DateNow = new Date();
var time = ("0" + DateNow.getHours()).substr(-2) + ':' + ("0" + DateNow.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 15000);

// определяем номер смены, в зависимости от времени
var day = DateNow.getDate();
var shift = 1;
//shift - смена
if (DateNow.getHours() >= 7) {
  if (DateNow.getHours() >= 15) {
    if (DateNow.getHours() < 23)
      shift = 3;
    else {
      DateNow.setDate(DateNow.getDate() + 1);
      day = DateNow.getDate();
    }
  } else
    shift = 2;
}
```

Comment: Проверьте, правильно ли понял: на входе - текущее время, на выходе - номер смены и её график, начиная с текущего дня. Что поправите?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Номер смены я получаю, нужна буква. Ну или если в решении это будет логичней, номер смены (1, 2, 3) и буква. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Исправил ошибку и учёл правило 23 часа**. Проверьте результат, пожалуйста.

```js
// что сейчас
var now = new Date();

// сколько полных часов
var hour = now.getHours();

// какая сейчас смена
var shift = 0;
if (hour < 7) {
  shift = 1;
} else if (hour < 15) {
  shift = 2;
} else if (hour < 23) {
  shift = 3;
} else {
  shift = 1;
};

// номер дня с начала года
var dayNewYear = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - dayNewYear;
var dayOne = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var dayYear = Math.floor(diff / dayOne);

// номер дня с начала 15-дневного цикла
// вычитаем 1, чтобы получить номер от 0 до 14
// если уже 23 часа, то считаем день завтрашним и добавляем 1
var lenShift = 15;
var dayShift = (dayYear - 1 + (hour < 23 ? 0 : 1)) % lenShift;

// графики групп
var group = [
  {name: 'А', schedule: 'ВВ111ВВ333ВВ222'},
  {name: 'Б', schedule: 'В333ВВ222ВВ111В'},
  {name: 'В', schedule: '222ВВ111ВВ333ВВ'},
  {name: 'Г', schedule: '11ВВ333ВВ222ВВ1'},
  {name: 'Д', schedule: '3ВВ222ВВ111ВВ33'}
];

// какая сейчас группа
var groupNum = -1;
for (var key in group) {
  if (group[key].schedule[dayShift] == shift) {
    groupNum = key;
  }
}

// график, начиная с сегодня
var scheduleShift = group[groupNum].schedule;
scheduleShift += scheduleShift;
scheduleShift = scheduleShift.substring(dayShift, dayShift + 15);

// проверка
//alert('Сегодня ' + now + '. День с начала года ' + dayYear + '. День с начала цикла ' + dayShift + '.');

// результат
alert('Смена ' + shift + '. Группа ' + group[groupNum].name + '. График, начиная с сегодняшнего дня ' + scheduleShift + '.');
```

Comment: Выводит -  Смена 2. Группа Б. График, начиная с сегодняшнего дня 22ВВ111ВВ333ВВ. 

На сейчас должно быть - Смена 2. Группа А. (средняя - вчера была и завтра будет)

Смена "Б" была в крайней (последней) ночной.

Comment: @VasilyUK Исправил ошибку. Проверьте ещё раз, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, теперь выводит нужный график и смену. Посмотрю как будет в ночную (там из-за часа пред идущего дня, когда смена наступает, к примеру 01.01.2016 в 23:00, а в графике она отмечена как 02.01.2016) и с переходом в следующий месяц. Спасибо за решение!!!

Comment: @VasilyUK Т.е. сегодня в 23:01 надо показывать график, как будто уже завтра?

Comment: @VasilyUK Учёл переход через 23 часа. Напишите, всё ли в порядке.

Comment: Да, всё работает. У меня в скрипте раньше описывается "DateNow". Сделал так: `var now = DateNow;` Погонял по датам и числам, посмотрел разлитые варианты (время же локально с компа), сравнил с графиком - всё Ок!! Спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял задание, то выводит:
Смена: 2 Имя смены В График: 2 2 2 В В 1 1 1 В В 3 3 3 В В

```
teams = [
    {name: 'A', work: 'В В 1 1 1 В В 3 3 3 В В 2 2 2'},
    {name: 'Б', work: 'В 3 3 3 В В 2 2 2 В В 1 1 1 В'},
    {name: 'В', work: '2 2 2 В В 1 1 1 В В 3 3 3 В В'},
    {name: 'Г', work: '1 1 В В 3 3 3 В В 2 2 2 В В 1'},
    {name: 'Д', work: '3 В В 2 2 2 В В 1 1 1 В В 3 3'}
];

DateNow = new Date();
var time = ("0" + DateNow.getHours()).substr(-2) + ':' + ("0" + DateNow.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
window.setTimeout(time.callee, 15000);

// определяем номер смены, в зависимости от времени
var day = DateNow.getDate();
var shift = 1;
//shift - смена
if (DateNow.getHours() >= 7) {
    if (DateNow.getHours() >= 15) {
        if (DateNow.getHours() < 23)
            shift = 3;
        else {
            DateNow.setDate(DateNow.getDate() + 1);
            day = DateNow.getDate();
        }
    } else
        shift = 2;
}

alert('Смена: ' + shift + ' Имя смены ' + teams[shift].name + ' График: ' + teams[shift].work);
```

Comment: нет привязки к календарю. Перечень смен был приведен как стартовый на 01.01.2016.  Сама периодичность смен бесконечная, но ложиться на календарь. То есть, на сейчас - 28.04.2016 в 12:15 (с 07:00 до 15:00) смена "А", 2 (средняя из трёх).